# Get length of current array in recursive ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Have a look in this fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/uXbn6/4619/

Here I have used recursive templates for printing my data.
What I want is 'Hi' text should only get printed only when correspondind array length is greater than 1.

Here for first array 'tree', as length is greater than 1, Hi should be printed. Now in child when repeat loops on data.nodes, as length of data.nodes is 1 or less than 1, 'Hi' should not be get printed.

In short I want output like this for this example

> firstParenNode Hi
>       node1.1
>       secondParenNode Hi

```
<script type="text/ng-template"  id="tree_item_renderer.html">
    <div> {{data.name}}
    <span ng-show="tree.length > 1"> Hi </span>
  </div>
    <div ng-repeat="data in data.nodes" ng-include="'tree_item_renderer.html'"></div>

 </script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="TreeController">
    <div ng-repeat="data in tree" ng-include="'tree_item_renderer.html'"></div>
</div>


angular.module("myApp", []).
controller("TreeController", ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.tree = [{
        name: "firstParenNode", 
        nodes: [{
            name: "node1.1",
            nodes: []
        }]
    }, {
        name: "secondParenNode",
        nodes: []
    }];
}]);
```

Any Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Try it:

```
<script type="text/ng-template"  id="tree_item_renderer.html">
    <div> {{node.name}} 
        <span ng-show="node.nodes.length > 0"> Hi </span>
    </div>
    <div ng-repeat="node in node.nodes" ng-inlude="'tree_item_renderer.html'"></div>
</script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="TreeController">
    <div ng-repeat="data in tree">
        <div> {{data.name}}
            <span ng-show="tree.length > 1"> Hi </span>
        </div>
        <div ng-repeat="node in data.nodes" ng-include="'tree_item_renderer.html'"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

See on my Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/uXbn6/4622/

Comment: OP said he wants 'Hi' to print if the node length is greater than 1, not 0. With that in mind this solution prints 'Hi' on a parent node even if there were not more than 1.

Comment: He want output "secondParenNode Hi". How it possibly in that conditions? secondParenNode length is not greater than 1

Comment: aah, now i understand. I edit my answer. In 12 string add "ng-show = tree.length>1"

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, just replace

`<span ng-show="tree.length > 1"> Hi </span>`

with

`<span ng-show="data.nodes.length > 1"> Hi </span>`.

Comment: But what about parent array, i.e. '$scope.tree', If I replace it, as you suggested it will show Hi only on child nodes not on root node

Comment: It should print 'Hi', if the current looping array has length greater than 1

Comment: Right now it looks like `$scope.tree` is not a node itself, but rather an array of objects. Each object is an actual node with a name and an array of child nodes. My suggestion should print what your example shows.

Comment: No, its not printing what I have, See in question, I have added desired output in my question, your suggestion is not printing 'Hi' at all

Comment: That's because none of the `nodes` arrays have length > 1. Like I said, `$scope.tree` is not being printed; it is not a node. Perhaps you want the length of the parent array's nodes instead of current? In which case you'll probably want to change your array structure to have one root node object with a name and `nodes` array which contains all other nodes.

Comment: So do you mean, I can't get current looping array length, in this kind of problem?

Comment: I sort of hacked together a solution here: http://jsfiddle.net/c39ngkbm/1/. I inserted a root node, and use multiple `$parent`s to get the node length of the parent. It's not pretty and can probably be improved.